# Isometric,Eccentric,Concentric training differences and what each is good for?

Tags: weightlifting, bodybuilding, strength-training

As in the title I wish to know:

1. What each of them is?
2. What each of them is good at?(muscle building ,strength building,resistance building,etc.)
3. Why should we include them in our training program?
4. What are the downsides of each of them?What about upsides?
5. Give a real life example on how to do each of them reported to ones 1RM at an exercise on choice(bench-press for example).
6. How to correctly execute each of them.

Comment: You can learn more about those terms, and answer most of your questions about them, by searching the internet.  But, why do you want to choose your training program in terms of those types of muscular contraction?

Comment: You can search the internet and find about them but most of them are very different from trainer to trainer to youtuber to youtuber.I trust this site more than all 5k views youtuber.

Comment: @CCCV Even bodybuilding.com sometimes contradicts itself ,depending on who wrote that article.

Comment: Plus, isn't one of the points of SE is to be a knowledge base? Seems like a great question for that reason.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't qualify against the one question per post rule. This is very broad in scope and reads more a like a homework question. It probably should have been closed when first asked, but it was missed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, some definitions:

- *Muscle length* is (for practical purposes) the distance between a muscle's origin and insertion.
- *Isometric* ("same length") muscular contraction occurs without a change muscle length.
- *Concentric* muscular contraction occurs with a decrease in muscle length.
- *Eccentric* muscular contraction occurs with an increase in muscle length.

Replies to your questions:

1. You could identify or contrive exercises involving isometric, eccentric, and/or concentric contractions, and build a training program upon these exercises.
2. Each of these types of muscular contraction can be trained to increase strength ("resistance"), and therefore muscle size.
3. Most strength training exercises (and, therefore, training programs) will include all three of these types of muscular contraction, because they are *how muscles work*.  For example, in the squat, the glutes and quadriceps (among other muscles) undergo both eccentric and concentric contractions, which the trunk muscles (for example, the spinal erectors and the abdominal muscles) undergo mostly isometric contraction.
4. Eccentric contractions tend to cause more muscle soreness than the other types of contractions.
5. The bench press involves both eccentric and concentric contractions of the triceps and the pectoral muscles, and isometric contractions of the spinal erectors and the abdominal muscles.
6. There aren't incorrect ways to execute these types of muscular contractions.