# Which exercises provide an eccentric load to the gluteus minimus?

Tags: exercise, recovery

Which exercises provide an [eccentric](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/q/32646/3806) load to the gluteus minimus?

I found exercises that provides eccentric load to the gluteus medius and maximus, but haven't found anything eccentric for the gluteus minimus yet. I don't want any concentric load to the gluteus minimus/medius.

Comment: Concentric load means shortening the muscle against resistance. Eccentric load is lengthening a muscle under load. As an example, on the bench press, the pressing movement is the concentric part, and lowering the weight to your chest is the eccentric part.

Comment: @RoryAlsop I don't want any concentric load to the gluteus minimus/medius, but I'm ok with eccentric load on medius or any load on maximus.

Comment: It's certainly possible to design an exercise that eccentrically but not concentrically loads the gluteus minimus, but why on Earth would you want to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The primary function of the [gluteus minimus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gluteus_minimus) is hip abduction, similar to the [gluteus medius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gluteus_medius). The gluteus minimus is deep to the gluteus medius. The different muscles provide different attachment points in the hip, which provides them with more leverage during certain angles. Through a full range of motion, all hip abductors are used.

Since in a [concentric](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3899915/) move the gluteus minimus performs hip [abduction](https://www.machinedesign.com/medical/what-s-difference-between-abduction-and-adduction-biomechanics) (swinging your leg away from your body, hinging at the hip), the [eccentric](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3899915/) activity would be in resisting hip [adduction](https://www.machinedesign.com/medical/what-s-difference-between-abduction-and-adduction-biomechanics).

You could accomplish this with bands. Put a band around your ankle, with the banded-ankle winged out. Slowly pull your leg back into anatomical neutral. Your gluteus minimus will lengthen under tension, counteracting the abduction.

The more typical way of doing this is the [lateral band walk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5wUk8wQNUT8). You'll be activating the gluteus minimus and gluteus medius concentrically when you abduct (move your leg away) and eccentrically when you adduct (bring the leg back in).

Just looking at this part of your question:

> I don't want any concentric load to the gluteus minimus/medius.

Then you wouldn't do the lateral band walks and would just focus on adduction, which would put all of the hip abductors into eccentric mode. I'll skip past the part about asking if this is a good or bad idea, but this is how you'd do it.

Answer (score 0):

{1} studied the activation of the gluteus medius (GMed) and gluteus minimus (GMin) for  7 gluteal rehabilitation exercises, viz. (A) hip hitch, (B) hip hitch with toe tap, (C) hip hitch with hip swing, (D) isometric hip abduction, (E) sit-to-stand, (F) dip test, (G) clam.

Exercise description:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Muscle activation:

[image]

According to the study:

> Numerous studies have reported on the ability of exercises to elicit high levels of GMed activity; however, few studies have differentiated between the portions of the GMed, and none have examined the GMin.

---

References:

- {1} Ganderton, Charlotte, Tania Pizzari, Jill Cook, and Adam Semciw. "Gluteus minimus and gluteus medius muscle activity during common rehabilitation exercises in healthy postmenopausal women." journal of orthopaedic & sports physical therapy 47, no. 12 (2017): 914-922. https://dx.doi.org/10.2519/jospt.2017.7229